# How can I enhace the perfomance of an animation that requires calling a function every time the mouse moves?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, animation, styled-components

So, essentially, I made the background image of a div follow the mouse cursor. However, I'm concerned that it may not have followed best practices in terms of performance. What can I do to enhance the performance of my code?

REACT

```
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import GlobalStyles from './styles/global';
import * as C from './App.styles';

import { Coordinates } from './types/types';

const App = () => { 

const [logoPosition, setLogoPosition] = useState<Coordinates>({x: undefined, y: undefined});
const logoRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

const handleCbrtOperation = (number: number) => {
  let operation = Math.cbrt(number)*3;
  if(operation > 100) {
    return 100;
  } else if (operation < -100) {
    return -100; 
  } else {
    return operation;
  }
}

const mouseMove = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => {
  setTimeout(()=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    if (
      logoRef.current?.offsetLeft !== undefined &&
      logoRef.current?.offsetTop !== undefined &&
      logoRef.current?.offsetWidth !== undefined &&
      logoRef.current?.offsetHeight !== undefined  
      ) {
        setLogoPosition({
          x: handleCbrtOperation(event.clientX - (logoRef.current.offsetLeft+(logoRef.current.offsetWidth/2))),
          y: handleCbrtOperation(event.clientY - (logoRef.current.offsetTop+(logoRef.current.offsetHeight/2)))
        })
  
      } else return;
  }, 100)
}

  return (
    <C.AppContainer onMouseMove={mouseMove}>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <C.Logo ref={logoRef} coordinates={logoPosition} />
    </C.AppContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

STYLED-COMPONENTS

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import logo from './assets/img/logo.png';
import backgroundComponent from './assets/img/background-component.jpg';
import { Coordinates } from "./types/types";

interface Props {
    coordinates: Coordinates;
}

export const AppContainer = styled.div`
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
`;
export const Logo = styled.div<Props>`
    position: relative;
    background: url(${backgroundComponent});
    background-position: ${p => p.coordinates.x}% ${p => p.coordinates.y}%;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    mask-image: url(${logo});
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-position: center;
    -webkit-mask-image: url(${logo});
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-mask-position: center;
`;
```

I've attempted to implement a timeout in the 'moveMouse' function to reduce the frequency of function calls, but I'm unsure if it's sufficient or beneficial.